# Add the result of SELECT query in another SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the result of a UNION of two SELECT

```
SELECT count(*) FROM
((SELECT session_id_current_user from test.tws_analytics 
        WHERE (add_date BETWEEN '2022-05-15' AND '2022-05-15') AND ((pathURL='vues/login.php' AND name_current_user='') OR (pathURL='' AND searchURL='?job=forgotten' AND name_current_user=''))
        AND session_id_current_user NOT IN 
        (SELECT session_id_current_user from test.tws_analytics 
        WHERE (pathURL <> 'vues/login.php' AND searchURL <> '?job=forgotten') AND add_date BETWEEN '2022-05-15' AND '2022-05-15' order by session_id_current_user)
        order by session_id_current_user)
    UNION 
(SELECT name_current_user from test.tws_analytics where add_date BETWEEN '2022-05-15' AND '2022-05-15' AND name_current_user IS NOT NULL AND name_current_user <> ''))
AS tem
```

The result is 11.

What I want to do is to select this result with other columns like this :

```
SELECT count(session),count(name), [AND tem.count(*)] FROM ....
```

This is the general idea, though i didn't know how to implement it.

Comment: Can you share your schema and sample data in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simplified general answer would be

```
select * from (select count(*) numsessions from sessions), (select count(*) numusers from users)
```

this will give 2 different counts, i didn't include the logics that you provided, but that will need to be done inside the 2 subqueries.

Comment: i did the exact same logic and it worked thank you :)